# Load data when scrolling to listview

Tags: android

I want to load data when user scroll . The loaded data is combine at the end of the ListView.
I test this feature . I found endless scroll in android .But I use this when the user scroll at the end of the list loading still appear and can't click on listitem . How can I know when the data end ?

Answer (score 4):

For example, you could use this code within your getView method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View row, final ViewGroup parent) {

...
  if (position > lastViewed && position == getCount()-1) {
      lastViewed = position;
      runTask(); //I immagine an AsyncTask which fetch data from the net or from a local  db
  }
...
}
```

Of course in your hypothetical `AsyncTask` you do not have to clear the adapter on onPreExecute but just adding the new items.

Sorry but the question is a bit too generic, without knowing the stucture of your code it comes complicated to answer, anyway I hope it will help.